# my servlet mapping spoil my filter

Tags: java, servlets, filter, mapping

In my program any url in the form of `/Controller/*` is redirected by my servlet mapping to `Controller` class.

I tried to add a filter for authantication, if user is not logged in and path is not `/Controller/RegForm` it's redirecting to `/Controller/RegForm`.

Problem is because my servlet mapping redirects to `/Controller`, filter always gets the `/Controller` as path.

How can I use both filter and the servlet mapping ?

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

my filter:

```
@WebFilter("/Controller/*")
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // If you have any <init-param> in web.xml, then you could get them
    // here by config.getInitParameter("name") and assign it as field.
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath();

    if ((session != null && session.getAttribute("student") != null )||(excludeFromFilter(path))) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Log 
        }
     else {
        response.sendRedirect("/registration-war/Controller/RegForm"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
    }
}

private boolean excludeFromFilter(String path) {
    if (path.equals("/Controller/RegForm")) {
        return true; // add more page to exclude here
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your filter implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `HttpServletRequest.getServletPath()` which returns the servlet URL which is (according to your servlet mapping) `"/Controller"`.

You want the [path info](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) not the servlet path:

> Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string and will start with a "/" character.

So for example this will return `"/RegForm"` if your user requests the `/Controller/RegForm` page.

```
String pathInfo = HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo();
```